# Are only IP-Addresses Blacklisted or also Domains?

Tags: ip, domain, blacklist

Unfortunately one of the forms of my website was used to send completely sensless spammails. As I found out through "http://mxtoolbox.com" that my IP-address is listed on two blacklists, I want to set up a new IP-address. However, I don't know if only IP-addresses get blacklisted or also domains. Please can anyone help . . . Many Greetings

Comment: Getting a new IP is easier than getting off dozens of blacklists but you're only on two.  It's also irresponsible as it passes the problem on to whoever gets that IP next.  Your hosting provider also suffers - with enough blacklisted IPs often an entire hosting provider will be blacklisted.

Answer (score 4):

1. Fix your website first.
2. Both can be blacklisted, but it's usually just the IP. Different lists keep different information.

Answer (score 4):

Each blacklist deal has its own blacklisting/whitelisting method.

Some use domains, some use single IPs (/32), some bigger ranges (/24).